# Setting process priority with psutil

Tags: python, process, psutil

I want to ask if there is some other and faster way of setting process priority in python then this:

```
for p in psutil.process_iter():
     if p.name() == "someProcess.exe":
          p.nice(psutil.HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS)
```

Note: I want to use psutil.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're first looking for a certain process based on its name. The only other possible (and fastest) way is if you know the PID upfront. I don't think this (your way) represents a serious bottleneck though. You typically set priority only once, likely on process startup.